# Do there exist $P$ and $Q$ such that $PAQ$ is jordan canonical form of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, do there exist an invertible matrix $P$ and a monomial matrix $Q$ such that $PAQ = J$ is the Jordan canonical form of $A$?

Comment: This question is not really at research level, but this answer might be helpful. The Jordan Canonical Form requires an algebraically closed field in general, so the question is not entirely well-posed. The result is true for an invertible matrix $A$ with eigenvalues in the base field, since you can take $P = JA^{-1}$ and $Q = I$. It is not true in general.

Comment: Left multiplication by an invertible matrix corresponds to row operations on a matrix, so the row-span is preserved. Putting a rank one matrix into RREF gives a matrix an arbitrary first row and all other rows zero. But the JCF of such a matrix will be non-zero only in the (1,1) entry, and this cannot be accomplished by a monomial transformation in general.

Comment: The condition that $Q$ be a monomial matrix also strikes me as peculiar. I'd be interested to hear about the motivation for this question. I agree with Padraig Ó Catháin that you really need to clarify what you mean by Jordan canonical form since finite fields are not algebraically closed.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ instead of $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.  The exact question is when  $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.